# google script assining variable bug

Tags: javascript, variables, google-apps-script

I've noticed strange bug while setting a new value to a variable. Unfortunately the Value has been copied to a different variable as well. Do you have an idea what is going on here?
Here are some screen shots while debugging. One just before setting the new value and one just after. You can see how automatically the value has been copied to 2 different variables.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Here is the file if you want to check it yourself:

docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17L7KDVteaYUuBE8v5jRRUGBBHa5_Dg6dH0eQ8oDTde4/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug.
Assigning arrays to variables happens by reference (to a memory location) in JavaScript and most other programming languages.
Consider this simplified example

```
a=[1];
b=a;
b[0]=2;
```

`a` is now `[2]`

To assign a copy you need to create a copy for example using slice

```
c=a.slice();
c[0]=3;
```

`a` will now still be `[2]` and `c` will be `[3]`.

So try

```
red = temp[i].slice();
```

Comment: Thanks so much friend :)